# Open emacs application in a specific mode for given path

Tags: macos, emacs, magit

I was using emacs on command line and I was using following command to open current git directory in magit mode:

```
emacs -nw -f magit-status --eval "(call-interactively #'delete-other-windows)"
```

I switched to using emacs app instead of opening it in command line. I am using following command alias:

```
alias emacs='open -a /Applications/Emacs.app $1'
```

Because of this magit command doesn't work anymore. Is there any way to achieve the same functionality with Emacs app?

Also, tried this function as suggested in comments:

```
function magit() {
 open -a /Applications/Emacs.app --args -f magit-status $1
}
```

Regards,
Pawan.

Comment: Use the `—args` argument to `open` to pass arguments to the application.

Comment: Thanks didn't work for some reason. I guess the way app and terminal emacs works is totally different. Is there any way to find out flags that I can pass while opening emacs app?

Comment: What did you do and how did it not work? If you're still trying to cram it into an _alias_ think about using a _function_ instead.

Comment: Sorry should have added more info. I tried function as well. It just focuses on existing opened emacs window and then doesn't do anything. I have tried closing all the windows but in that case this command is just opening emacs.

Comment: Added function to the main post. let me know if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: In a `sh`/`bash` shell function (at least), `$1` passes only the *first* argument (and unquoted at that).  That is never what you want from a wrapper function.  If that's what is happening here, you actually want `"$@"` which passes *all* arguments, each quoted appropriately.

Comment: Conversely, I don't know what the `$1` is doing in your shell `alias` definition at all.  When you use an alias, everything following the alias in the command is appended to the alias' expansion.  You're *probably* adding an unquoted empty string there, which is going to be harmless; but it's still a bug by the looks of it.

Answer (score 1):

When starting a new Emacs session, the function

```sh
function magit() {
 open -a Emacs --args --file "$1" -f magit-status
}
```

will do what you want. That is, load a file into a buffer (via `find-file`) and run the function `magit-status` on that buffer. Note, that order counts on the Emacs command line. While `open -a Emacs myfile --args -f magit-status` and `open -a Emacs --args -f magit-status myfile` are correct from the perspective of `open`, they aren't correct from Emacs's perspective. (`magit-status` is executed on nothing, and then `myfile` is opened. Not what you want.)

If you want to do this with a currently running Emacs session, you can't. The clue is in `open`'s manpage.

> ```
> --args
>     All remaining arguments are passed to the opened application in the argv parameter to main().  These argu-
>     ments are not opened or interpreted by the open tool.
> ```

`main()` has already executed, so you can't pass anymore parameters to it, so `--args` is effectively ignored. So, you'll have to get creative with the Emacs server and `emacsclient`.

If you have an open Emacs session with an associated server (via `server-start` for instance), you can do the following to "load and execute-on" a file

```
# my emacs will load *.log files in `fundamental-mode`
# this will load them in `text-mode`

$ emacsclient -e '(find-file "/tmp/foo.log")' -e '(text-mode)'

# or

$ emacsclient -e '(progn (find-file "/tmp/foo.log") (text-mode))'
```